# Seeking synonyms for "prices move in step" or "prices move in unison"

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

I am looking for synonym expressions to say "prices move in step" or "prices move in unison".

The number of "prices" mentioned in the above examples are indefinite, but very large.

I have not been able to find anything reliable in dictionaries.

Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with "in step"?

Comment: Nothing. I am just looking for equivalent alternative expressions.

Comment: An example sentence and a description of what you're trying to convey would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When you're talking about prices moving, my vote is for **in tandem** [with each other].

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, "in tandem" is not appropriate for more than two prices, which is the case here. We need to find alternative expressions. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/325536/in-tandem-can-it-be-used-with-more-than-2-things

Answer (score 0):

> "Prices move in-step" or "Prices move in unison"

The meaning of these phrases would be **together.**

One definition of [together](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/together) that Merriam Webster gives is:

> : at one time : SIMULTANEOUSLY (e.g.
> *events that happened together*)

Synonymous phrases that have the same meaning of an undetermined amount of things 'happening together' are:

- [in sync](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20sync)

> in a state in which two or more people or things move or happen
> together at the same time and speed

- [en masse](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/en-masse)

> in a mass; all together; as a group:

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think that "in tandem", "in sync" and "en mass" mean exactly the same that "in step" or "in unison"? Can I use them as perfect synonyms in my example sentence? I am not native and it is hard for me to tell if there is any subtle difference in meaning.

Comment: Allow me to edit my answer to give you definitions for these phrases to help you decide, but yes they are synonyms to the meaning that you have in your sentence.

Comment: "en masse" is spelt with a final e: I don't know how you manage to link to the correct spelling but get it wrong! Also it isn't normally used for just two things moving together, and implies a larger number/group.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the typo. It has been fixed. :) The OP did not specify if the "prices" were just two, so en masse would fit as a synonym.

Comment: In the example sentence, prices are more than two. It refers to an idefinite, very large number of prices. So I guess that "in tandem" is not appropriate.

Comment: I added this context to your question for clarity.