# "In tandem" - Can it be used with more than 2 things?

Tags: expressions

I have a doubt on the expression "in tandem".

Can more than two things "move in tandem"?

Or is it always limited to two things as one would expect from the tandem bike origin of the expression (a bike for two individuals)?

Example with two things (the "copper price" and the "index") - So I guess it is correct:

> The copper price moves in tandem with China's industrial production index

Example with more than two things ("asset prices" refers to an indefinite, very large number of assets) - I am not sure if it is correct:

> Asset prices move in tandem throughout the cycles

Comment: Tandem always applies to **two** things. More than two things move **together**.

Comment: That's what I tend to think too, but in my research I have found several examples in newspaper articles and books where tandem is used for more than two things. Unfortunately I cannot copy those examples because of copyright.

Comment: Did you look in any dictionaries? Cambridge Dictionary (British) says 'two things working together' Merriam-Webster (American) says 'a group of two **or more** ... acting in conjunction'.

Comment: Yes. Definitions are contradictory, as your message shows. That's why I am asking. Logic would suggest that tandem applies only to two things because of the bicycle origin but then it seems to be accepted sometimes or by some for more than two things. As I am not native, I cannot tell if the use feels okay for more than two things, as in my example sentence ("Asset prices move in tandem throughout the cycles"). Having said this, the majority of examples that I found in my research involved only two things, which is maybe telling.

Comment: FWIW, copying snippets of text from a copyrighted source to ask questions is legal. A large number of questions on this site are based on mainstream print journalism and as many answers include direct quotes from online dictionaries.

Comment: It's probably one of those things where you can use it with more than 2 things, but there is a risk someone will complain and say it's wrong. People disagree about what is right and wrong, and some people like to find fault. So avoid it if you're worried about criticism, keep it if you don't care.

Comment: Thank you. My takeaway is that I should look for alternative expressions for more than two things. Maybe "in sync"? "Asset prices move in sync throughout the cycles"

Comment: @gotube Can members in this forum copy the definitions of words as found in online dictionaries (apart from Wiktionary) and paste into answers here in this forum? Is it illegal? I have seen people providing definitions  from OED and other online dictionaries.

Comment: @banuyayi Yes, it's a regular practice here to supply quotes from copyright media, dictionaries in particular. I myself include quotes from Merriam-Webster in maybe a quarter of my answers.

Comment: Oh, okay then. I am in the clear:)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tandem), a definition of **in tandem** is:

> a group of two or more arranged one behind the other or used or acting
> in conjunction

I disagree with the notion that **in tandem** only applies to two things, and this confirms that it does not, at least according to Merriam-Webster.